# How to use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation without web.xml?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I have read that from *JavaEE 6* `web.xml` is optional.

So without *web.xml*, how can I tell the application server to use Jersey as the implementation for JAX-RS specification?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[What @AlexNevidomsky wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729590/2587435) in his answer is correct, as far as how to implement the app configuration with no web.xml; you use an [`@ApplicationPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation on an [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends Application {}
```

For more information on deployment options, see the [Jersey Docs: Chapter 4. Application Deployment and Runtime Environments](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Or more commonly, with Jersey as implementation, we would extend `ResourceConfig` (which extends `Application`).

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("package.to.scan");
    }
}
```

**So how is this implemented...**

First things first, not all Java EE servers use Jersey. Actually the only ones I know that use Jersey are Glassfish and WebLogic. JBoss uses Resteasy. Tom EE uses CXF. WebSphere uses Apache Wink. Those are the only ones I can think of.

So I guess the question is "How does the Server know how to load the JAX-RS application?"

Servlet 3.0 introduced the pluggability mechanism, which makes use of a [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). How it works is that when the Server/Servlet container is started, it scans jars for a `META-INF/services` folder with a file named `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. This file should include one or more fully qualified names of implementations of the `ServletContainerInitializer`.

This interface has only one method

```
void onStartup(java.util.Set<java.lang.Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)
```

The `Set<Class<?>` will be a list of classes, fitting the criteria in the [`@HandlesTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html) annotation on the `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation. If you look at Jersey's implementation

```
@HandlesTypes({ Path.class, Provider.class, Application.class, ApplicationPath.class })
public final class JerseyServletContainerInitializer 
                   implements ServletContainerInitializer {
```

You should notice some familiar annotation classes, as well as the `Application.class`. All these classes matching the criteria, while scanning, are added to the `Set` passed to the `onStartup` method.

If you scan the rest of the source code, you will see all the registration being done with all of those classes.

Resteasy uses

```
@HandlesTypes({Application.class, Path.class, Provider.class})
public class ResteasyServletInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer
```

I won't get into to others.

**Some source you can look at...**

- [`JerseyServletContainerInitializer` source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.33/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java)
- [`ResteasyServletInitializer` source code](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-servlet-initializer/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/servlet/ResteasyServletInitializer.java)
- [JAX-RS specs](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=370)

Comment: So, can I delete web.xml in my Jersey project?

Comment: @mFeinstein You need a _complete_ JAX-RS implementation. Tomcat does not have one.

Comment: After lots of searching, I made it work with HK2 DI, In my case (I am using the AWS Lambda Serverless Framework for Jersey and Tomcat for local testing) I needed to add `implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.28'` and change Tomcat `webapp` folder permission on Windows 10, because IntelliJ can't deploy inside `Program Files`.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha curiously, I can't make it work on GlassFish 5. it crashes if I add HK2 DI, I guess GlassFish CDI doesn't play well with it.

Comment: @mFeinstein If you are using Maven, make all your Jersey dependencies `provided` in scope. Glassfish already has all the jars in its library. You will just need them for your app to compile.

Comment: Yes, they were like this (but in Gradle), but I changed them for Tomcat, as Tomcat needs them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify anything in web.xml. Define an activator class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class _JaxRsActivator extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

  static {
      //Check some system init on REST init.
      Config.initCheck();
  }
}
```

Comment: But how does the server know to use jersey?

Comment: If you are interested in technical details, take note that you define a path mapping there. So on the first request for this path prefix the initialization happens: the servlet container calls ResteasyDeployment.start(). At least that's what JBoss does.