# in jersey 2.x am getting the error like java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

1. i have used the jersey implementation of a jaxrs but iam unable to the programme following is case where i am getting problem any idea help me

   in following programme i used the jersy 2.x implementaion of jaxrs 
   i implemented the programme using jersey implemetation of jax-rs(restfull)
   2 classes i have written instead of web.xml i used the class

   MyResource.java

   ```
   package com.rest.application;

   import java.util.HashSet;
   import java.util.Set;

   import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

   import com.rest.webservice.SampleService;
   @ApplicationPath("rest")
   public class MyResource {
       private Set s;
       public MyResource() {
           s=new HashSet();
           s.add(new SampleService());
       }
        public Set getSingletons() {
           return s;
       }
   }
   ```

   SampleService.java

   ```
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
   import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
   import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

   @Path("sample")
   public class SampleService {
       @GET
       @Produces("text/html")
       @Path("{username}")
       public String sayHello(@PathParam("username")String s) {
           return "<font color='blue' size=8>Hello:" +s+ "</font>";
       }
       @GET
       @Produces("text/plain")
       public String sayBye() {
       return "Bye";
   }
   }
   ```

   i added the all jars needed to this programm
   still i am getting following error

   ```
   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
   Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].
   StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestApp2]]
   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
   Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].
   StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestApp2]]
   ```

   like this same error is displaying everywhere

   when i changed the server tomcat 7 to 6
   it is working but not displaying the output 
   will anybody have any idea thanking you in advance

Comment: please clean your code...can't read

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) says, `@ApplicationPath("rest")` may be applied only to the subclass of Application.

Can you share more on what are you trying to do and what is the complete stack trace. Are you using web.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

As @MSD mentioned, your use of `@ApplicationPath` is incorrect. See the Jersey documentation on [Application Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) to see all the different deployment options, and how they work in different environments.

Basically, the easiest way put the `@ApplicationPath` on an empty `Application` class

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {}
```

This will scan the entire classpath for `@Provider` and `@Path` annotated classes, to register with the application. Though this may seem easier, the more common approach, when working with Jersey is to use it's [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) class, which is a subclass of `Application`. You can register packages, which will scan the packages and subpackages

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("com.my.packages");
    }
}
```

One benefit is that sometimes there will be third party dependencies that are annotated, but you don't want registered. To register individual classes just use `register(...class)` in the `ResourceConfig`.

Now the reason for the error in Tomcat 7 and not 6, is most likely because Tomcat 6 (servlet 2.5) does not have the sevlet pluggability mechanism, which uses the `ServletContainerInitializer`. The Jersey implementation of this initializer loads the application, looking for the `@ApplicationPath` on the `Application` subclass. If you're not in a 3.0 environment, this functionality will not work.

Note the Jersey initializer is included in the `jersey-container-servlet` jar. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730471/2587435)