# How do you deploy resteasy 3 ResteasyServletInitializer with Resn 4.0.36 or newer?

Tags: java, maven, resteasy, resin

I have been unable to get the ResteasyServletInitializer to initialize properly in Resin 4.
I get a log as follows

```
[15-10-06 12:23:22.651] {resin-29} Annotation @WebFilter at 'org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Filter30Dispatcher' must specify either value, urlPatterns or servletNames
```

I can manually add the servlet declaration and set the context-param resteasy.providers to comma separated list of providers and get it working without the ResteasyServletInitializer.

My maven pom.xml has the following dependencies in it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have no idea what Resin is but in a normal servlet container, you just need an [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass annotated with [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729363/how-to-use-jersey-as-jax-rs-implementation-without-web-xml/29730471#29730471)

Comment: Resin behaves according to the spec: The urlPatterns attribute, servletNames attribute or the value attribute of the annotation MUST be specified.