# Jersey 2.22: Where should I define the location of REST resources?

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, resources, jersey

Currently, I know two ways:

1. Specify it as an `<init-param>` on you web.xml
2. Create a class that extends `ResourceConfig` and add it on your web.xml

I have this class that extends `ResourceConfig` because I needed to register an Application Binder (`AbstractBinder`) for dependency injection.

Where should I define the location of my REST resources? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

In the `ResourceConfig`, you can call `packages("reource.packages")`, which will do the same as scanning the package declared inside the `<init-param>`

```
public class Config extends ResourceConfig {
    public Config() {
        packages("...");
        register(new AbstractBinder()..);
    }
}
```

To use the `Config` class, you have a couple options.

1. Annotate it with `@ApplicationPath("/appPath")`

   With this, no web.xml is required. You need to make sure you have the `jersey-container-servlet` dependency for this to work. The value in the annotation works the same way as the `<servlet-mapping>` inside the web.xml.
2. Declare the `Config` class inside the web.xml

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>org.foo.Config</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>
   ...
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/myPath/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

You could also *not* use the `ResourceConfig` and register the binder inside a `Feature`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275727/2587435)

**See Also:**

- [Application Deployment and Runtime Environments: Servlet-based Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)
- [How to use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation without web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729363/2587435)