# ContainerRequestFilter wont run in JavaEE jersey project

Tags: rest, maven, jersey, java-ee-7

Am new to JavaEE and have some issues getting custom ContainerRequestFilter to run in Jersey. I read the jersey documentation some more and created a new clean project straight from the '***jersey-quickstart-webapp***', added the filter seen below but no luck (added an empty beans.xml as well).

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("User cannot access the resource.").build());
    }
}
```

Was uncertain if Prematching and Provider was complementary or not so i used both then each separately, but didnt work (MyReasource just served as without filter). Tried throwing an exception in MyFilter but that didnt run either.

So i searched through StackOverflow and found 'http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/' which points to that you actually needs to implement registrations in Application or ResourceConfig class. I tried this (didnt work) but i atleast got a warning for the resource class now, '***No resource methods have been found for resource class a.b.MyFilter***'

My Application class now looks like below (tried scan package but didnt make a difference. Without the manual filter registration i didnt get the warning either).

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        //packages("a.b");
        register(MyFilter.class);
        register(MyResource.class);
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>a.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>server</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

All files lies in the 'a.b' (i.e my package) root. Any ideas on how to get the filter actually running and i would be very greatful ;). I presume it shouldnt be this hard to get this working so i guess im missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me walk you through what's going on. When you first created the `jersey-quickstart-webapp` archetype, it gave you this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>a.b</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

What this init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` does is tell Jersey what package(s) to scan for resource classes annotated with `@Path`, and provider classes annotated with `@Provider`.

So from that point, all you needed to do was add the `@Provider` to the filter, and it would have worked.

But then you decided to clear out the web.xml and use the `ResourceConfig` with the `@ApplicationPath`. For this to work Jersey takes advantage of the Servlet 3.0 pluggability mechanism, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730471/2587435). For that to work we need to make sure we have the jar that has the `JerseyServletContainerInitializer`. That's where we need to look at the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
    <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
</dependency>
```

The comment is telling you that if you don't need Servlet 2.5 support, you should use `jersey-container-servlet` instead of `jersey-container-servlet-core`. I don't know, it might be poorly worded. Maybe instead it should say if you want Servlet 3.x support, change it. But in any case, the `jersey-container-servlet` has the `JerseyContainerServletInitializer` that we need. So if you want to go web.xml-less, then just switch out the dependency.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared things up a LOT for me. I understood that xml setup was legacy so thats why i used Application. I, however, had no idea regarding the dependency, i presumed it was just added backwards compability. So as it was set as default i didnt think of changing it.

I did however notice that while it now works perfectly on glassfish (Servlet 3.0 pluggability mechanism) it just generates Error 500 om TomEE+ however. I guess this could be a dependency issue (root cause NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map). 

Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: TomEE still uses JAX-RS 1.1. Jersey 2.x uses JAX-RS 2. The two are incompatible. When try and run the Jersey 2 app the older JAX-RS classes get loaded and Jersey tries to call a method that JAX-RS 1.1 doesn't have. Even with Glassfish you may run into problems down the line as it already has a version of Jersey. But it is very old. So best thing to do is put your Jersey dependencies in a `provided` `<scope>`. That was the jars don't get built into the final app. Glassfish jars are used. It's possible though to upgrade Jersey in Glassfish if you wanted to