# Glassfish error when producing JSON

Tags: json, xml, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I developed an Android app and now I'm starting with its external DB and its server, the communication is performed by RESTful web services.

This Android aplication just produces and consumes info in JSON, so in my web services facades I just want to erase any mention to XML in the CRUD methods, (automatically generated by NetBeans).

I mean, from this:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Counselor> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

To this (without the MediaType.APPLICATION_XML):

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Counselor> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

The thing is that when I deploy these changes in my GlassFish Server (4.1.1) and do some tests with my browser (just want to see my DB data) I get an error with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.validateAndTransformIfNeeded(JAXBMarshaller.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:949)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea about this?

I hope I explain myself...thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a bug in Glassfish 4.1.1 https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2888

I was able to fix it in a dirty way:

In glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar fix META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Just append the following to Import-Package:

```
,org.xml.sax.helpers,javax.xml.parsers;resolution:=optional,javax.naming;resolution:=optional
```

so it looks like after:

[image]

and restart GF

btw: you can easy edit jars in terminal with

```
emacs org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar
```

Comment: Are there any plans to release a fix for glassfish?

Comment: Yeap, that was it, thanks a lot : ). I've just fixed it thanks to this post: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169 I was going to post it here right now when I saw your answer. @cebor I've read that it was already fixed (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2888), but it seems not

Comment: For those who doesn't use the terminal, as long as JAR files are zip files, you can extract and modify them using any zip extractor.

Comment: I followed all the steps and It didn't workout in my case

Comment: is this fixed in 4.1.2?

Comment: This bug is also present in 4.1.2. Fixed easily with `vim org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar` :)

Comment: I tested this issue on GlassFish 5.0 and it is resolved.

Comment: Thanks @hannes. It saves my day

Answer (score 10):

Jack's answer is really helpful.
It pinpoints the problem and was useful when there was no patch.

But I suggest **instead of editing the jar**, since the bug is corrected in 2.6.1,
to **download it** at :
[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.1 from MVNRepository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.6.1/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.1.jar)

OR get the latest version from MVNRepository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy

and replace it.

Don't forget to close and reopen you IDE.