# How to edit META-INF/MANIFEST.mf

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

i am facing problem in java web service REST and the solution of the problem is to add this line:

```
,org.xml.sax.helpers,javax.xml.parsers;resolution:=optional,javax.naming;resolution:=optional
```

in **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**.
just like in this previous problem here:
[Glassfish error when producing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json)
However i can't edit this file, is there any way to edit it?
By the way i am using windows 10 so i can't use terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your jar file into .zip file. Open it with Windows Explorer. The paste into META-INF your new MANIFEST.MF file. And finally rename .zip back to .jar file.