# 500 (Internal Server Error) when send json to restful web services java

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, rest

I am working on a web service to insert data into a sqd server, as I am new to this, I am doing small tests.

You have created a rest web service in netbeans, create a person entity, the only thing that the service does is receive an object in xml or json format and then store it in persistence. When I send an xml format like this:

```
<persona>
<idPersona>20</idPersona>
<nombre>Albert</nombre>
<trabajador>true</trabajador>
</persona>"
```

Works fine, but when I send the object in json format like this:

```
{
"idPersona":"20",
"nombre":"Bernard",
"trabajador":"true"
}
```

I get a 500 (Internal Server Error). I have been guiding a tutorial online, I followed all the steps, in the tutorial there are pictures and everything is perfect, but in my case it is not like that.

Did someone have the same problem? I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to look at the server log to see what error caused the 500.  The 500 is like the Check-Engine light, it tells you nothing other than that something failed.  Also, do not post images of code.  Copy/paste the actual code into your post.

Comment: You should add the necessary information quickly if you want to avoid downvotes for insufficient information.  If necessary, delete your post and undelete it when you can add the server log stack trace.

Comment: @JimGarrison, Excuse my ignorance, but where would you see the record you're writing?

Comment: You should have access to the server log files.  If your server runs on your system you'll have to look for them.  The specific location will depend on the server (Tomcat, JBoss, etc) and how it was installed.  If someone else manages the server you'll have to ask them.

Comment: I'm working locally with glassfish

Comment: In NetBeans go to the "Services" tab open "Servers", right-click on your Glassfish instance and click "View Domain Server Log".?

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this?

Comment: Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

Comment: at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:257)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.validateAndBuildJAXBElement(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:235)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660)

Comment: at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)

Comment: Don't post stack trace in comments. Please [edit] your post, and format as code (use the `{}` button)

Answer (score 2):

You treat your boolean like a string and persona is missing. But your json should look like this:

```
{
  "persona": {
    "idPersona": "20",
    "nombre": "Bernard",
    "trabajador": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Also try without quotes in true, but the result is the same

Comment: You can't say this definitively without seeing the stack trace.

Comment: Apparently it's a glassfish bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json

Comment: @JulioRafael Sorry, edited my answer. Take this json. This should work