# Returning Json From Jersey on Linux Throws Exception

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

I've developed a Jersey API which returns either XML or JSON (depending on the request header). When deployed on my Windows 2012 server (Tomcat), it works no problem.

When I deploy (after compiling it on Ubuntu) to an Ubuntu machine in AWS (Glassfish), I get the following errors when I request JSON:

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

root cause org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
```

No errors when I request XML.

I was originally using moxy for JSON serialization, but then started using Jackson.

Any ideas why it would work on one server and not another?
Thanks

Comment: Might be a bug of Glassfish. Please refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json).

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Yeah I saw that. I figured they must have fixed it by now. Apparently not ...

Comment: What if you put all your Jersey related dependencies as "provided"? Remember that Tomcat has no Jersey jars in it, so there is no conflict. But Glassfish _does_ have Jersey. So your project jars might conflict. So you should exclude them from the deployment when deploying to Glassfish, and just use the ones provided by Glassfish.

Comment: @peeskillet I gave it a shot and added a scope element to the dependency for the moxy package with a value of "provided". I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you please update question with glassfish version? Seems to be a glassfish bug, see the comment from `sentonimo` [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21141)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. First, use Tomcat, not Glassfish.

Then, add a new dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also upgraded Jersey version to 2.26, but I don't think that made the difference. Just adding that for completeness (as it did happen).

I don't understand the reason it works. I always thought Java ran the same on Windows and Linux. But hey, I'm just a dumb .NET guy.

Hope this helps others who find themselves in a pit of helplessness on this issue as I did.