# Exception when executing method :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

When i run http://localhost:8080/domain/account, it returns a ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

When i remove the parameter User in the createUser method, it runs successfully. am i missing a pom dependency?

```
import com.domain.model.User;

@Path("account")
public class AccountController {

  @PermitAll
  @POST
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public Response createUser(User user) {
    return Response.ok("asasd").build();
  }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>account</groupId>
  <artifactId>account</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
             <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
             <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.42</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: " i missing a pom dependency?" if you don't show them, hard to answer.

Comment: Whar are your dependencies?

Comment: added pom in original post

Comment: your pom seems fine even if     `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` is a little surprising. I have found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json It should help you. And I close as it is a duplicate.