# unable to pass object as method parameter

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to pass a person object to my test method below but i am getting an error when i try to run it in postman. Any help will be greatly appreciated

In postman, i used the following JSON in the body

```
{
    "name" : "aasd",
    "address" : "asd",
    "age" : "asdads",
    "sex" : "asdsad"
}
```

**Person model**

```
package com.test.model;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person{
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String address;

    public Person() {

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.test2.controller;

import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.test.model;

@Path("person")
public class PersonController {

    @PermitAll
    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("test")
    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        return person;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

Comment: Where do you define what fields must be passed to Person model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glassfish error when producing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json)

Comment: JFPicard, i tried to edit the manisfest of the moxy.jar as mention in that thread but it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Do you POST with `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @diginoise yea, in my header, theres Content-Type with the value of application/json

Comment: apparently a bug in GlassFish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722764/glassfish-error-when-producing-json   What version are you running? Can you test your code with another server?

Comment: 4.1.2.    i can probably try to downgrade the server to try

Comment: downgrading does not help