# REST WebServise - how to use service like a singleton?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

My rest application contains a service and I need to make this service to act like a singleton to save a state of the service.

a service:

```
@Path("/script")
public class ScriptEngineProvider {

private AtomicInteger idCounter;

public ScriptEngineProvider() {
    System.out.println("before AtomicInteger");
    idCounter = new AtomicInteger();
}

@POST
public Response executeScript( String x ) {
    idCounter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("counter " + idCounter);
    ...
```

a client besides all other code has:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/NashornEngine/rest").path("script");
```

web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

With the above configuration the application works but with every request the variable `idCounter` creates so `idCounter` is allways `1`.

Now I use next class to make the `ScriptEngineProvider` to be a singleton:

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class NashornApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    public NashornApplication() {
        singletons.add(new ScriptEngineProvider());
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get `The requested resource is not available` with request:

```
//path services was added
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/NashornEngine/rest").path("services").path("script");
```

What is the problem with this config?

Comment: the whole service doesn't have to be a singleton. Only idCounter needs to be static...

Comment: @jHilscher, let is `idCounter ` will be a static and how could that help if `ScriptEngineProvider ` is new with every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ApplicationPath` effectively serves the same purpose as the `url-mapping`. But only one can be used. You use `@ApplicationPath` with an `Application` subclass when you don't want to use web.xml configuration. To go web.xml-less, you need to make sure of two things

1. You are deploying to a 3.x servlet container.
2. You have the dependency that supports the servlet pluggability. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730471/2587435)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

It's also possible to use an `Application` subclass *without* the `@ApplicationPath`, which will then use the `url-mapping` to map the Jersey servlet. For example

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.pkg.YourApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which ever way you choose, either the `url-mapping` path will be used, or the `@ApplicationPath` value will be used, but not both. So in your case, if you do with no web.xml configuration, the path would not include the `/rest` in the `url-mapping`. And if you go with the above web.xml configuration, then you should get rid of the `@ApplicationPath` on your `Application` subclass, that url you would use would with `/rest`, with no `/services`.

The reason you keep getting one is because

1. The default behavior is to create a new resource class for every request
2. Your `Application` subclass is not being used, and your web.xml configuration is being used, where you are package scanning.

Review the information from this post, and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: It works the only problem which is Eclipse makes Application class with erorr while annotation is missing `The Application Path should be configured with an @ApplicationPath annotation or in the web deployment descriptor.` even if web.xml configured.

Comment: Shouldn't be an error, but a warning. Same thing happens in Netbeans. If you really don't like the warning then go web.xml-less. See above for the requirements

Comment: The other point is that app works even if annotation `@ApplicationPath("")` is present with all that web.xml stuff.

Comment: It'll work even you you add `@ApplicationPath('boomshakalaka")`. The annotation isn't being used. Your url-mapping is being used

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@Singleton // this is the important line
@Path("/script")
public class ScriptEngineProvider {

private AtomicInteger idCounter;

public ScriptEngineProvider() {
    System.out.println("before AtomicInteger");
    idCounter = new AtomicInteger();
}

@POST
public Response executeScript( String x ) {
    idCounter.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("counter " + idCounter);
    ...
```