# How to make jersey and @webservlet working together

Tags: java, jsp, networking, jersey, servlet-filters

[image: directory structure]

How to make jersey and @webservlet working together ?

jersey ResourceConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(Greetings.class);
    }
}
```

jersey Resource registered in resourceConfig:

```
@Path("/login")
public class Greetings {
    @GET
    public Response getHelloGreeting(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        System.out.println("In the Greetings resource");
        String url= "http://"+httpRequest.getServerName()+":"+httpRequest.getServerPort()+httpRequest.getContextPath();
        String newURL = url+"/login.jsp";
        System.out.println(newURL);
        return Response.seeOther(URI.create(newURL)).build();
    }
}
```

web servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet", urlPatterns = { "/hello" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
            System.out.println("inside login servlet");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println("request forwarded");
        }
    //other functions not important so deleted
}
```

Case 1: on accessing this 
    http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/login

console logs:

> ```
> In the Greetings resource  
> http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/login.jsp             (no ui comes)
> ```

on accessing this
    http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/hello

> ```
> (nothing happens 404 error)
> ```

Case 2: Changing application config resource path:

```
@ApplicationPath("/auth")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(Greetings.class);
    }
}
```

on accessing this
    http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/auth/login

> ```
> In the Greetings resource  
> http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/login.jsp             (Ui comes)
> ```

on accessing this
    http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/hello

> ```
> inside login servlet                                          (Ui comes)
> userid is
> Encoded string 
> request forwarded
> ```

doubts:
don't know why login.jsp is blocked in the first case:

why http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/login       not showing any ui .. i think it should come ?
why http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/hello       not showing any ui ?

Answer (score 1):

Using asterisk (`*`) won't work using [@ApplicationPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874188/jax-rs-application-on-the-root-context-how-can-it-be-done)

> If you use /*, then you're making it too greedy and saying it should match everything all the time, and the default servlet will never be invoked

Use `@ApplicationPath("/")` instead

> If you use /, then you're replacing the container's default servlet

Comment: can you tell why ? because sometimes it works on my other projects !

Comment: @akitsme follow the link for further details

Comment: now  the request is forwarded to servlet and resource .. but still the ui is not coming. http://localhost:8088/ResponseFilterweb/login.jsp  404 error

Comment: @akitsme See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977419/how-do-i-render-a-new-jsp-file-in-the-browser-using-jersey-for-java

Answer (score 1):

If you were using web.xml, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29076059/2587435) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428843/2587435) would be your solution, but since you're not, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047149/2587435) might be your only option. The problem is that when you use `/*` as the servlet mapping for Jersey, it hogs up all the requests. So the request to `/hello` would go to Jersey and not the `LoginServlet`. What those solutions I linked to do is cause Jersey to forward the request if it can't find it within the Jersey application. The other solution is to just change the servlet mapping to something like `/api/*` (which is pretty common), then you would just prefix your API requests with `/api`.