# Automatically register ClientResponseFilter and other providers with the Jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Is there any way to automatically register a `ClientResponseFilter` without using `register()` method on a `WebTarget` or `Client`?
I'm looking for something simillar to the `@Provider` annotation which can be used only in a `ContainerResponseFilter`/`ContainerRequestFilter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no scanning capabilities implemented in the client side. The closest thing you will get to automatic registration is with the use of [SPIs (Service Provider Interfaces)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html). Any SPI supported will be specific to the JAX-RS implementation. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357807/2587435), you can see how a `MessageBodyReader` may be implemented as an SPI, and a JAX-RS implementation *may* automatically register it.

As mentioned though, it is up to the JAX-RS implementation to decide what SPIs it wants to support. With Jersey, the most generic SPI is the [`AutoDisoverable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357807/2587435).

```
public interface AutoDiscoverable {
    public void configure(FeatureContext context);
}
```

You just implement this interface, registering any providers you want with the `FeatureContext`. Then you create a file

```
/META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
```

and just put the fully qualified name of your implementation into that file. The Jersey runtime will discover this file and call your `configure()` method.

One example of the `AutoDiscoverable` is the [`JacksonAutoDiscoverable`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/JacksonAutoDiscoverable.java#L56). And [the SPI file](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/media/json-jackson/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable). When we add the [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) dependency to our project, Jersey will find the SPI implementation of the `AutoDiscoverable` and will call the `configure()` method, which registers the `JacksonFeature`, so we don't need to manually register it ourselves.

The use of the auto-discoverable, or most SPIs in general, is for use with reusable libraries. Usually for a project where your provider is used only for that specific project, adding the auto-discovery capabilities to the provider just adds unnecessary work. It's easier to just register the provider manually. But if you want to create a library that can be reused, and you want the user to not have to explicitly register any providers or features, then you might want to implement the auto-discovery.

---

#### Some more details

If you *are* going to implement the `AutoDiscoverable`, one thing I should mention is that we can put a constraint on which runtime it should be applied to; client or server, We do that with the `@ConstrainedTo` annotation.

```
@ConstrainedTo(RuntimeType.CLIENT)
public class MyAutoDiscoverable implements AutoDiscoverable {}
```

If your `AutoDiscoverable` registers a `ClientRequestFilter`, then you wouldn't want the server to register this, so you would constrain to the client runtime.