# JAX-RS EJB container

Tags: jax-rs, ejb

I have an .jar application (using ejbs) deployed as part of an .ear archive.
Inside this .jar application I have classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Stateless`.

My question is: Are my JAX-RS resources going to be deployed inside an EJB container or inside WEB (Servlet) container? Do I need to define web.xml and to put servlet definition inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are my JAX-RS resources going to be deployed inside an EJB container or inside WEB (Servlet) container?

It will be deployed to the servlet container of your EE server.

> Do I need to define web.xml and to put servlet definition inside of it?

Not necessarily. You can configure a JAX-RS application simply by having an empty `Application` subclass annotated with `@ApplicationPath`<sup>1</sup>.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {}
```

If you want to use a web.xml, you can instead of this class. If you do want to, just look for a tutorial to show you how to do it. But this class is all that is needed for the most basic configuration.

---

#### Footnotes

1. See [How to use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation without web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729363/2587435)